# Loop Through Array and Store as New Array - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

This is simple but I can't find anything. I have an array that I want to loop through, pull up a specific attribute for each, and then store those attributes in a new array.

Basically:

- store `array2 = [Array1[0].attr, Array1[2].attr, Array1[3].attr]`

What I have

```
<% storedArray = [] %>
<% @data = current_user.data_items %>
       <% @data.each do |data_item| %>
          <% storedArray[data_item.count] = data_item.url_metric.da %>
       <% end %>
```

Updated:

I got it to work but in a really bad way. Suggestions?

```
<% array = []; i = 0 %>

   <% @data = current_user.reports[0].data_items %>
   <% @data.each do |data_item| %>
      <% array[i] = data_item.url_metric.da %>
      <% i = i+1 %>
   <% end %>
   <%= array %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the method [collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect)

It returns a new array with the values created after the loop through the source array. In your problem the code would be:

```
# Get initial array
<% @data_items = current_user.reports[0].data_items %>

# Iterate through original array and return value to new array
<% @array = @data_items.collect do | data_item | %>
    # Process item
    <% data_item.url_metric.da %>
<% end %>

# Now your new array is ready to go.
<%= @array %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<% @array= current_user.data_items.map {|data_item| data_item.url_metric.da} %>
```

You can directly use the resulting array by using each like the following:

```
<% current_user.data_items.map {|data_item| data_item.url_metric.da}.each |result| %>
# Do something with the result
<% end %>
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html for more list operations.